# Get All Entities From EntityCollection Where Values Matches X

Tags: linq, dynamics-crm, entity, entitycollection

I would like to get all matched `Entities` from an `EntityCollection` by a value, but my current statement only allow return of `Entity`, and not `EntityCollection`.

```
//only allow return 1 entity
var matchedRecords = allRecords.Entities.Where
                                (x => x.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>
                                                         ("ccc_batchId").Id == batchId);
```

May I know how can I tweak the above query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EntityCollection is just a construct to store more than one Entity.

I know it's not ideal but you can always convert the allRecords.Entities inside a List of Entity and do your LINQ query against it.

Your code is probably returning an IEnumerable of Entity and not a single Entity (for example in the end of your query you can put a .ToList() to get a List of Entity.

Answer (score 1):

Building on what Guido said, it is also possible to create a new [EntityCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.xrm.sdk.entitycollection?view=dynamics-general-ce-9) with the results:

```
var matchedRecords = allRecords.Entities.Where(x => x.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("ccc_batchId").Id == batchId).ToList();    
var matchedCollection = new EntityCollection(matchedRecords);
```